# How to write recursive function and print it in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a function that should take any list and then print it like this (e. g.):

Input list: `(A B C)`

Output: `(A B C) (A) (B) (C)`

That is the original list followed by each element in a list of its own.  The function should be written as a recursive function.

I have the following pseudocode which I couldn't get it right and cannot transform into recursive:

```
Assuming input (A B C)

Function input (list)

  Cons newlist '(list) //newlist = (A B C)

  newlist append (car list) //car returns A

  pop list//remove firstElement

  newlist append (car list)//car returns B

  Pop list

  newlist append (car list)//car returns C

  pop list

  Print newlist.
```

The problem here is that using Append, I will get (A B C A B C). Is there any other way to separate it into its respective brackets and also recursively?

Comment: @kuroineko Is this even helpful?

Comment: What is the output you want? `(A B C (A) (B) (C))` or `((A B C) (A) (B) (C))`?

Comment: @LePetitPrince The second one

Comment: Please remember adding the `common-lisp` tag to your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for something like this:

```
(defun f (lst)
  (labels 
      ((g (lst)
         (when lst
           (cons (list (car lst)) (g (cdr lst))))))
    (cons lst (g lst))))
```

where the outer function `f` uses the inner, recursive function `g` and prepends the initial list.

```
? (f '(A B C))
((A B C) (A) (B) (C))
```

Basically `g` is the same as `mapcar` so, if you didn't have to do it recursively, you could do instead:

```
(defun f (lst)
  (cons lst (mapcar #'list lst)))
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is your escape shuttle, Sigourney :)

(tested with a vintage GNU common LISP windows build - I had to retype the session by hand since it appears copy-paste was still a sci-fi concept when this thing was compiled)

```
>>(defun explode_list (input)
   (if (null input)
    nil                            ; list termination
    (cons 
      (list (first input))         ; create singleton list with first element 
      (explode_list (rest input))  ; concatenate with the rest of the list
  )))

EXPLODE_LIST

>> (explode_list '(a b c))

((A)(B)(C))

>>(defun do_weird_thing_with_a_list (l) (cons l (explode_list l)))

DO_WEIRD_THING_WITH_A_LIST

>> (do_weird_thing_with_a_list '(a b c))

((A B C) (A) (B) (C))
```